# can we make slider in select options?

Tags: html, css

can we make slider/carousel in select options.below is the code and image.anyone help plz.

```
<select class="" id="project_type" name="project_type" title="Project Type"  multiple 
style="width: 410px;">
                                              
<option value="Residential" <?php if($selected_project_type == 'Residential') echo "selected"; 
?> >Residential</option>
                        
<option value="Commercial" <?php if($selected_project_type == 'Commercial') echo "selected"; ? 
> >Commercial</option>
                        
<option value="Residential & Commercial" <?php if($selected_project_type == 'Residential & 
Commercial') echo "selected"; ?> >Residential & Commercial</option>

<option value="Infrastructure" <?php if($selected_project_type == 'Infrastructure') echo 
"selected"; ?> >Infrastructure</option>

<option value="Others" <?php if($selected_project_type == 'Others') echo "selected"; ?> 
>Others</option>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoYb0.png)

i want all select options inline and put slider.

Answer (score 0):

Selects are pretty hard to customize

A way easier will be just make slider
and change an input or even div properties when click on slide